# Technical name for a region of memory with a fixed pattern for bounds checking?

Tags: memory, nomenclature, bounds-checker

I want to know if there is some technical name for those regions of extra memory that are allocated for debugging purposes and filled with special patterns, so they can be checked at runtime to see if have been overwritten (and thus detecting a possible buffer overflow)...

A fellow referred to them as "Canarios" (Canaries in Spanish), I think it is an analogy to the canary birds that were used in the mines to detect the firedamp, but I'm not sure if the same name is used in English.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've heard guard block before.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there's an idiomatic metaphor that's commonly used. The phrase "guard region" is sometimes used.

Answer (score 2):

Some people call it "no man's land", see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127386?sort=newest).

Answer (score 1):

I've actually heard 'canaries' used in English too.